# How do I get a display: grid div to take up the whole screen in IE 11? (100vh doesn't seem to work)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I have this rather complex layout that I was trying to create with CSS grid:

## How it's supposed to look

[image: How it's supposed to look with grid layout]

## IE:

[image: How it looks in IE]

As you can see we need this resizable banner that squishes the content down on the main page *but* doesn't make the page scroll. I think for some reason IE doesn't support `vh` when you do `display: grid` for some reason and was wondering.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
    justify-content: stretch; 
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 10fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 10fr 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 50px auto 100px auto 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 100px auto 50px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav     nav        nav"
    "bar     bar        bar"
    "title   title      title  "
    "left    middle    right"
    "left    composer  right";

  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.nav {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-area: nav;
  background: teal;
}
.bar {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-area: bar;
  background: red;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dynamic-height 4s;
  animation: dynamic-height 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.title {
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-area: title;
  background: lightblue;
}
.left {
  overflow-y : scroll;
  -ms-overfow-y: scroll;
  -ms-grid-row: 4;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-area: left;
  background: yellow;
}
.middle {
  -ms-grid-row: 4;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: middle;
  background: green;
}
.right {
  -ms-grid-row: 4;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-area: right;
  background: brown;
}
.composer {
  -ms-grid-row: 5;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: composer;
  background: light-green;
  height: 30px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dynamic-height {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 200px;
  }
  0 {
    height: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes dynamic-height {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 200px;
  }
  0 {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="nav">
      nav
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      Resizeable Banner
    </div>
    <h2 class="title"> Title </h2>
    <div class="left">
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <p>Sidebar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <p>Messages</p>
    </div>
    <div class="composer">
      COMPOSER
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>Right Sidebar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I used https://autoprefixer.github.io/ to generate the CSS-Grid prefixes however the *one last thing* that doesn't work in IE 11 is *the scrollable sidebar.*

https://codepen.io/justgage/pen/EdXGEX

Comment: What version if IE are you using? I do not see what your gif shows in IE 11.0.9600.19129

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **overflow-y : auto** to **overflow-y : scroll;**

`overflow-y : scroll;`

OR

`-ms-overflow-y: scroll;`

It will add the scroll bar for IE.

Further, you can try to modify the CSS as per your requirement.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Now looking at it closer I think the problem is that `vh` doesn't seem to work on an element that's CSS grid'd 